# How to handle multiple forms in react

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

[image]

I have an accordion which has 7 steps.
first 6 steps has `Next` button and last step has `Process` button.
and above accordion there is a `Save` button.

Also one can jump to any accordion step any time.

**Save button** saves all step's forms data and checks validation.
Every step's **Next button** saves that particular form data and checks validation. **Process button** also submits all step's forms data and checks validation.

I have tried `redux-form`. but it is limited to particular step. what about **save button** click?

> [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrw3lkjrr4)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: screenshots added

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrw3lkjrr4

Comment: Please don't add screenshots, copy and paste your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getFormNames`, `getFormValues` and `isValid` [selectors](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/selectingformvalues/) to select your forms state.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    forms: getFormNames()(state).map(formName => ({
      formName,
      isValid: isValid(formName)(state),
      values: getFormValues(formName)(state),
      errors: getFormSyncErrors(formName)(state)
    }))
  };
};
```

Submit function:

```
submit() {
    const { dispatch, forms } = this.props;

    forms.forEach(({ formName, isValid, values, errors }) => {
      if (isValid) {
        console.log(values);
      } else {
        dispatch(touch(formName, ...Object.keys(errors)));
      }
    });
  }
```

> [Updated example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zqwq58j243)

Comment: looks good, how can I fire validation in those forms so it will display error